How to make the box bigger when an element is added to it? (CSS)
I'm a Django web developer and I'm beginner to html and CSS.
i have box in a html page and i use it as food list. I want it get more height when an element (new food) added to it. Thank you.
i searched google but I didn't found anything.

Can you elaborate? As is, what you are claiming for is the default behaviour of any html element with display=block until explicit size limitations are imposed.

You should elaborate the question to make it more clear.
Any way just try this or modify as per your requirements and check if this solves your problem.
In order to add food items dynamically you will have to use Js otherwise just with HTML, CSS your number of food items will be predefined.
//--------CSS-----------
#food-list {
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 10px;
    }

//--------HTML---------- 
<div id="food-list">
    <!-- Your food items will be dynamically added here -->
  </div>
  <button onclick="addFood()">Add Food</button>

//----------JS-------------
function addFood() {
      var foodList = document.getElementById('food-list');
      var newFood = document.createElement('div');
      newFood.textContent = 'New Food';
      foodList.appendChild(newFood);
    }

Modify it as per your requirements
